# JQuery Validation Plugin submitHandler doesnt work for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

Hello i got the following issue my following code doesn't work for me and i cant figure out why. I hope you guys can help me.

Edit: The submit handler simply doesn't get called. I don't even get the alert message. I wanted to disable the submit button till the form is validated.

```
    $('form').validate({

        onsubmit: true,
        debug: true,
        errorLabelContainer: "#errorBox",
        rules: {
            user_email: {
                minlength: 4,
                email: true,
                required: true
            },
            user_textField: {
                minlength: 3,
                required: true
            },
            user_phone: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                minlength: 4
            },
            user_fax: {
                number: true,
                minlength: 4
            },

            user_plz: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $('form').find(":submit").attr("disabled", true).attr("value","Submitting...");
            alert("hie");
            form.submit();
        }
    });
```

I also got a submit button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right continuePaymentProcess" type="submit">Weiter</button>
```

Best Regards Grandy

Comment: Saying 'it doesn't work' is not enough information. Please include details of expected behaviour, and what happens, and why it does not meet what you need.

Comment: The submit handler simply doesn't get called. I don't even get the alert message. I wanted to disable the submit button till the form is validated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the `onsubmit: true` line because that's the default behavior.  **Important**:  [as per docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate),

> Validate the form on submit. Set to false to use only other events for validation. Set to a Function to decide for yourself when to run validation. **A boolean true is not a valid value.**

In other words, you must remove that line because `true` will break the plugin.

As far as the `submitHandler` "not working", it works as per the documentation.  The `submitHandler` callback function fires *when the form is valid*.

You say, *"I wanted to disable the submit button till the form is validated."*

Since the `submitHandler` doesn't get fired until the the form is `valid`, your code to disable the button doesn't fire until *after* the form is validated.

See your code: http://jsfiddle.net/aDAGL/

Comment: Thank you, i just realized I tried to use the wrong handler. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue. Please check all the input elements in the form and provide "name" attribute to all the elements . This helped in my case.

Thank you