# Getting MVC 4 to validate all sections of jquery accordion form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I've got a big form that I split it up into sections, using the Accordion plugin for jQuery-UI.

[image]

When I click the form's submit button, MVC's server-side validation does not check all of the form's input fields - it **only** validates the fields of the current expanded section.

In this example, when I click submit, MVC only validates Section A.  If Section B or C haven't been filled out yet, it throws a crazy `NullReferenceException` error.  I want MVC 4 to **validate all fields in the Accordion** instead of just looking at just one.

Looking at the rendered HTML, the `<div class="ui-accordion-content">` elements that hold the other fields I would like to validate have `style="display:none"`.  I want MVC 4 to validate the undisplayed fields in addition to the displayed ones.

**EDIT :**
There are [many answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390801/mvc-validation-with-jquery-accordion) on Stack Overflow that suggest adding `ignore: []` to the jQuery validator settings should work.  It does not work for me, and the form submits regardless.

```
$("#GeneralForm").validate({
    rules: {
        GuestName: {
            required: true,
        },
        GuestID: {
            required: true,
        }, // etc.
    },
    ignore: []
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution ended up being ridiculously simple.  I have two scripts: one where the Accordion is instantiated, and the other where validation occurs:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Validation", "~/Scripts/Accordion")
```

The order matters; switching these two around fixed the problem.

Having the order reversed will:

- throw 0 console errors
- let MVC validate the form incredibly lazily; even if jQuery-validate knows some of the inputs are invalid, it won't prevent the form from posting
- will throw runtime `NullReferenceException` errors later on if you're using Entity Framework 5 (on `db.SaveChanges()`, specifically).

Additionally, the `validator` needed a custom `submitHandler` (which would open up panels according to whether or not the form fields they contain are valid; only posting the form if both areas passed a validation test) **and** `onsubmit: false`.  The default is `true`.  If it's true, and you're using a custom submitHandler, [everything silently implodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18358732/3474146).

Answer (score 2):

jquery validator ignores hidden elements by default, but you can disable this behavior:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        ignore: ""
    })
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like this is true (although I've read that one should use `ignore:[]` over `ignore:""`), but I edited my question to reflect that this is not working in my case.

Comment: @alex you can try to edit the jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js file. there is a validationInfo method with options where you can add the ignore property.